# Update datas from database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to update some data from a database and i have a problem in the code... It appears to be no errors but it doesn't update.

**conexiune** is my connector class
**cheltuieli** is my table in the database and the rest of the names are the columns

the error is on this line: **command.ExecuteNonQuery();** and the error appears when i click the button
**error:** A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''35', DistractieCultura '20', Neprevazute '30'' at line 1

I have no clue why... any thoughts?

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (textBox1.Text != "" & textBox2.Text != "" & textBox3.Text != "" & textBox4.Text != "" & textBox5.Text != "" & textBox6.Text != "")
                {
                    MySqlConnection conexiune = null;
                    conexiune = Conector.getConnection();
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
                    command.Connection = conexiune;
                    command.CommandText = "Update cheltuieli set Mancare = '" + textBox1.Text + "', Facturi = '" + textBox2.Text + "', Reparatii = '" + textBox3.Text + "', Altele '" + textBox4.Text + "', DistractieCultura '" + textBox5.Text + "', Neprevazute '" + textBox6.Text + "'";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Actualizat!");
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                    textBox3.Clear();
                    textBox4.Clear();
                    textBox5.Clear();
                    textBox6.Clear();
                    Search();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Put your query in a string and Print or Log it to check if query is well formed. also provide that sample query after replacing parameters if possible.

Comment: [About 12,700 questions on Stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+.net+sql+%22incorrect+syntax+near%22) relating to this error message.  the answer is almost always the same - Use SQL parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Every field that you want to update should be followed by the symbol = and then the value. Your query has the symbol only after the first field

```
 UPDATE table SET Field1='Value1', Field2='Value2' .....
```

Said that, you should immediately ditch this code and start using a parameterized query. With string concatenation, like you are doing now, your code could be hacked using a Sql Injection or you could face syntax errors caused by single quotes in your values

An example of parameterized query is

```
string cmdText = @"Update cheltuieli set Mancare = @mancare, 
                   Facturi = @facturi,Reparatii = @reparatii, Altele=@altele,
                   DistractieCultura = @distractieCultura, 
                   Neprevazute=@neprevazute";

using(MySqlConnection conexiune  = Conector.getConnection())
using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conexiune))
{
    conexiune.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("@mancare", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@facturi", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
     ... and so on for the other parameters ....
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Notice that your query doesn't have a WHERE statement, so this query updates every record present in the table cheltuieli with the same values. This is always an error, but I have no clues on what record you want to update.

Comment: i tryied with your code but the error remains at the exact same line **command.ExecuteNonQuery();** this program should be able to add,delete, update and view expences and in the add method i used that command.executenonquery and it worked and now everytime i use it it completely errors me. the values are just numbers and they are being updated from listboxes, where the data from the database is listed on categories

Comment: **Additional information: Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'**

Comment: i'm a beginner, it's just a thing for school and i am struggling with this error i have... with the update method and the delete method...

Comment: This is a different error. The table has a primary key and this means that no rows could have the same value in that field.

Comment: PrimaryKeys are columns that contains unique values and are used to identify a specific record between the set of records present in the table. You cannot have two record in which the PrimaryKey field contains the same value. Do you know what is the PrimaryKey field?

Comment: so i should just drop the primary key constraint?

Comment: "Mancare" is the primary key

Comment: No, you should not allow your user to change the primarykey value. It is the identity required to update the record .... _UPDATE table set field=value, ......  WHERE mancare=@mancare_

Comment: i get an error at the same freaking line. this time is a fatal error..damn it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114887/discussion-between-adriana-chiricioiu-and-steve).

Comment: Sorry @AdrianaChiricioiu but it was late in the night for me. Let me know if you need help.